# Updating a compose list item from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of items in compose that can have a button on them to do a task. When the task runs I show a progress bar instead of the button to indicate its doing something. The task relies on a system broadcast to know when its finished.

How do I report back to that compose list item to turn off the progress indicator for that one specific item while still keeping the current state of the other items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your view you may create a view model with a flow that indicates the task state. If you `collectAsState` that flow, you will be able to update your progress UI when you have changes:

```
val taskState by viewModel.taskStateFlow.collectAsState()
```

Inside your view model, I suggest you to use a `callbackFlow` like this:

```
 private val taskStateCallbackFlow: Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
        val stateBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                // When you receive the broadcast, update the flow with state
                trySend("finished")
            }
        }

        context.registerReceiver(
            stateBroadcastReceiver,
            // Use the intent filter that best fits your case
            IntentFilter(...)
        )

        awaitClose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(stateBroadcastReceiver)
        }
    }

    val taskStateFlow: StateFlow<String> = taskStateCallbackFlow.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        initialValue = "started"
    )
}
```

In this case the receiver will be unregistered if you leave your current page.

However, if you need to receive the broadcasts even if you are outside the progress page, you should statically declare your broadcast receiver and save the state in a database when you receive the broadcast. In that case change your view model to listen for database changes.